# Creating Multiple If, And, Or Statements

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a formula for tracking candidates who are clear, not clear, or pending for hire.  The result is based on a combination of answers that we type in columns E and G.  Here is my formula:

```
=IF(E3="Fail",IF(G3="Fail","Not Clear"),IF(E3="Clear",IF(G3="Neg","Completed"),IF(e3=”Pending”,If(g3=”Pending”,”Pending”),IF(e3=”Pending”,if(G3=”Neg”,”Pending”),if(e3=”Clear”,if(g3=”Pending”,”Pending”),If(e3=”Pending”,if(g3=”fail”,”Not Clear”),If(e3=”Fail”,If(G3=”Pending”,”Not Clear”),if(e3=”Fail”,If(g3=”Neg”,”Not Clear”),if(e3=”Clear”,If(g3=”Fail”,”Not Clear”,”Pending”))))))))))
```

I've tried a less involved formula, but it doesn't give me the correct answer for anything with "Fail" in E or G.

```
=IF(E11="Fail",IF(G11="Fail","Not Clear"),IF(E11="Clear",IF(G11="Neg","Completed","Pending"),IF(E11="Pending",IF(G11="Pending","Pending"))))`
```

I've tried it with the IF/OR statement, and also with the IF/And Statements, but getting error messages.

I've tried to build a Matching table on a separate tab called "lookup" to do a match lookup, but I'm not that experienced with that formula.

Any help is appreciated as I am trying to streamline as well as improve upon our current process here on our team.

Other versions of the formula that I've tried that don't seem to work:

```
IF(E3="Fail",G3="Fail","Not Clear"),IF(E3="Clear",G3="Neg","Completed"),IF(e3="Pending", g3="Pending","Pending"),IF(e3="Pending",G3="Neg","Pending"),if(e3="Clear",g3="Pending","Pending"),If(e3="Pending",g3="fail","Not Clear"),If(e3="Fail",G3="Pending","Not Clear"),if(e3="Fail",g3="Neg","Not Clear"),if(e3="Clear",g3="Fail","Not Clear","Pending"))))))))))

IF(E3="Fail",IF(AND(G3="Fail","Not Clear"),IF(E3="Clear",IF(AND(G3 ="Neg","Completed"),IF(e3="Pending",IF(AND(G3="Pending","Pending"),IF(e3="Pending", IF(AND(G3="Neg","Pending"),if(e3="Clear",IF(AND(G3 ="Pending","Pending"),If(e3="Pending",IF(AND(G3="fail","Not Clear"),If(e3="Fail", IF(AND(G3="Pending","Not Clear"),if(e3="Fail",IF(AND(G3="Neg","Not Clear"),if(e3="Clear",IF(AND(G3="Fail","Not Clear","Pending"))))))))))

IF(E3="Fail",G3="Fail","Not Clear"),IF(E3="Clear",G3 ="Neg","Completed"),IF(e3="Pending",G3="Pending","Pending"),IF(e3="Pending", G3="Neg","Pending"),if(e3="Clear",G3 ="Pending","Pending"),If(e3="Pending",G3="fail","Not Clear"),If(e3="Fail", G3="Pending","Not Clear"),if(e3="Fail",G3="Neg","Not Clear"),if(e3="Clear",G3="Fail","Not Clear","Pending"))))))))))
```

Spreadsheet in Excel is the following:

Sample Image of Spreadsheet for reference

[image: img1]

Comment: Can you add an example of data to test your formula?

Comment: Can you post your matching/lookup formulas and how you tried? I would think you can skip the convoluted `If(If(If(If(...` and do a more clear formula.  Also can you edit your example data into the original post? It's not very clear in the comments.

Comment: @Christy, please add the data as a table in the question. That way it can be used.

Comment: Here is the OR statement version that didn't work:   =IF(OR(E3="Fail",G3="Fail","Not Clear"),IF(OR(E3="Clear",G3="Neg","Completed"),IF(OR(e3="Pending", g3="Pending","Pending"),IF(OR(e3="Pending",G3="Neg","Pending"),if(OR(e3="Clear",g3="Pending","Pending"),If(OR(e3="Pending",g3="fail","Not Clear"),If(OR(e3="Fail",G3="Pending","Not Clear"),if(OR(e3="Fail",g3="Neg","Not Clear"),if(OR(e3="Clear",g3="Fail","Not Clear","Pending"))))))))))

Comment: This is the AND version that didn't work:  IF(E3="Fail",IF(AND(G3="Fail","Not Clear"),IF(E3="Clear",IF(AND(G3 ="Neg","Completed"),IF(e3="Pending",IF(AND(G3="Pending","Pending"),IF(e3="Pending", IF(AND(G3="Neg","Pending"),if(e3="Clear",IF(AND(G3 ="Pending","Pending"),If(e3="Pending",IF(AND(G3="fail","Not Clear"),If(e3="Fail", IF(AND(G3="Pending","Not Clear"),if(e3="Fail",IF(AND(G3="Neg","Not Clear"),if(e3="Clear",IF(AND(G3="Fail","Not Clear","Pending"))))))))))

Comment: This was another version that I tried that didn't work: IF(E3="Fail",G3="Fail","Not Clear"),IF(E3="Clear",G3 ="Neg","Completed"),IF(e3="Pending",G3="Pending","Pending"),IF(e3="Pending", G3="Neg","Pending"),if(e3="Clear",G3 ="Pending","Pending"),If(e3="Pending",G3="fail","Not Clear"),If(e3="Fail", G3="Pending","Not Clear"),if(e3="Fail",G3="Neg","Not Clear"),if(e3="Clear",G3="Fail","Not Clear","Pending"))))))))))

Comment: Sorry, but I can't seem to get the spreadsheet sample to load into the comments or the original question I posted.....It looks fine until I post and then it doesn't stay formatted.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want your logic to be then you can use IF with OR to accomplish this.

Assuming: any value of fail results in not clear.  Any value with pending is pending and anything that doesn't have fail or pending but has clear is complete. (I didn't see a scenario for NEG but assumed from the picture it didn't matter as no NEG - NEG rows existed)

```
=IF(OR(E2="FAIL", G2="FAIL"), "Not Clear",IF(OR(E2="PENDING",G2="PENDING"), "Pending", IF(OR(E2="CLEAR", G2="CLEAR"),"Completed", "ERROR")))
```

Comment: Try:IF ( OR (E3="Fail",G3="Fail"),"Not Clear",IF ( OR (E3="Pending",G3="Pending"),"Pending",IF ( OR (E3="",G3=""),"Data Missing","COMPLETED")))

Comment: @JamesHawkins  you didn't improve the formula and a NEG-NEG row will be listed as completed.

Comment: I was working on this at the same time, arriving at essentially the same result. After, I noticed yours a few minutes prior to mine. In any case, I deleted mine. // I did not understand that NEG NEG resulted in a fail. If it does not, yours would need to be modified. // Also, I would think an IF to make sure both cell are one of a set of possibilities would be useful. Otherwise, someone might put in "failed" instead of "fail," assuming this is just typed into, only to have this return completed.

Comment: @JamesHawkins I can't say NEG-NEG is a fail but put it as an error as there was no example of it in the data provided.  I would suggest the user use data validation drop downs on the cells E and G to ensure the correct values are entered each time as otherwise you are correct they will get false positives

Comment: The Formula that @JamesHawkins presented works perfectly! I have already included the data validations for the E & G cells to prevent typos.  Thank you so much for your help! It is very much appreciated :)

Comment: @Christy you do realize they are basically the same except one checks for blanks and the other for Clear.  Glad you have it working, not so much you chose the commented one as your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose you a couple of possible solutions. First of all you should define your cases. I would suggest you to fill in a simple table. I tried to understand the logic behind your IF formula and I come out with this table:

[image]

**1. Solution with INDEX/MATCH formula:**

My favorite solution is using a formula with INDEX/MATCH, because it is more easy to set once you have written the table and you do not risk to make mistakes by nesting IF conditions. Assuming that the above table is on Sheet1, the formula is like this:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$C$28:$E$30,MATCH(YourSheet!G3,Sheet1!$B$28:$B$30,0),MATCH(YourSheet!E3,Sheet1!$C$27:$E$27,0))
```

Basically the first argument of INDEX formula defines the range of the reference table, the second argument selects the row and the third argument selects the column. INDEX returns you the value of the selected cell in the range. MATCH searches the value of the first argument in the range defined in the second argument. Third argument in MATCH selects only exact values. So MATCH returns the number of the cell in the range where there is the value.

Please pay attention to use in your sheet only values defined in the column and row headings of the reference table. Otherwise MATCH formula returns you an error and INDEX formula cannot work.

**2. Solution with IF with OR and AND:**

If the reference table above is correct, a formula with IF, OR and AND could be the following:

```
=IF(OR(E3="Fail",G3="Fail"),"Not Clear",IF(AND(E3="Clear",G3="Neg"),"Completed","Pending"))
```

This formula should be rewritten in case you change the logic of the reference table.

I made a test and, as you can see here below, both formulas return same result:

[image]

If you need further support, drop me a comment here below.

Comment: the index table works very well too.  Thanks for showing me how to set that up as I've never used one before and this is great knowledge to have as well!